# java bean variable needs to change before submit

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a java bean I call with:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<jsp:useBean id="empower" class="com.sas.mis.empower.des.empower" scope="session">
    <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="*" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="acronym" value="ABS"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

In the bean it has setAcronym and getAcronym functions. The value is used by another function to make a `List<String>` projects based on the acronym supplied.

In that, something like:

```
List<String> getProAdministrators() {
    return project_admins.get(this.acronym);
}
```

You can see it uses whatever `setAcronym` set it to use.

Also, in my useBean I hard code the value to `ABS` on the page load, which is the first acronym in my drop down because I do not know of another way to set this. I would of course prefer some way to have it get the selected value of the drop down list and not have to even set this in the `useBean` definition.

The javascript `init()` creates a table of stuff using jstl/el based on the acronym set. I want on the event that the list box changes that the table is recreated using its new selected acronym.

The table creation is not slick for this testing:

```
function tableCreate(){
        var table = "<table>";
        var head = "<thead>";

        head += "<tr>";
        head += "<th>Administrators</th>";
        head += "<th>Developers</th>";
        head += "<th>Observers</th>";
        head += "<th>Users</th>";
        head += "</tr>";
        head += "</thead>";

        table += head;

        var body = "<tbody>";
        body += "<tr>";
        body += "<td>";

        // Administrators
        var cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${myBean.projAdministrators}" varStatus="status" >
            if (cell == "") {
                cell = "${item}";
            } else {
                cell +=",${item}";
            }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Developers
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${myBean.projDevelopers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=",${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Observers
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${myBean.projObservers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=",${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Users
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${myBean.projUsers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=",${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";
        body += "</tr>";
        body += "</tbody>";
        table += body;
        table += "</table>";
        domTarget("DOMTarget2",table);
}
```

Is there some way in the create table function to use something like setAttribute to set the acronym value in the bean so that when the user selects a new acronym from the listbox it will create the new table with the right information?

Comment: Use javascript/jquery and do it in the browser?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Java server code, including EL and JSTL, runs on server, not on the client.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know that. Where does *the user selects a new acronym from the listbox* run? I was specifically thinking of something AJAXy here.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in browser client. And that's the real problem. Stating OP to use javascript/jquery only (which run on client) may don't provide a guide on the complete solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch and the intention of the comment was...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is it possible (and acceptable) for the OP to use Javascript or jquery to solve their ultimate objective, which appears to be changing the acronyms displayed when a new acronym is selected from a listbox? It even has a question mark at the end.

Comment: The user list box is on the jsp page in a form.  Ajax appears to be just for reading data from a url you specify that has some fixed data.  It does not sound like javascript variable can be used by jstl or java because as mentioned javascript value is seen on the client and jstl/el is preprocessed on the server as it builds the page to send to the user. Can Ajax be used somehow to update the acronym bean value?  It would have to be some kind of action where request.getParameter("acryonm") returns the new listbox value dynamically.

Comment: Unless this is legacy code you're stuck with, I would say: Don't use jsp:useBean. A bean is just an instance of a class you store in the session, so just set it and retrieve it as you would any other session attribute.

Comment: @user Ajax usually reads dynamic data from a url (which cat include parameters). I have no idea why you'd limit it to static data.

Comment: Ajax can be used to submit data just like a HTML form submit but without reloading the page, which is what you want: Submit an ajax request with the form data, on server-side read it from the parameters, save it in the session.

Comment: The examples I see of ajax on the web read content of a php page or xml file and display the data into a div.  How do I use ajax to get the value of a parameter on the same page?